# DjangoでBootstrapがロードされない。

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Djangoのアプリを作っていて、Bootstrapを使いたかったのですが、読み込んでくれません。
ログは以下のように出ます。

```html
[07/Jul/2015 09:10:52]"GET /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1694
[07/Jul/2015 09:10:52]"GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1676
[07/Jul/2015 09:10:52]"GET /static/js/iquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
[07/Jul/2015 09:10:52]"GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1670
```

Settings.pyは以下のようになっています。

```html
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect'
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

ディレクトリ構成は以下のようになっています。

```html
Project
|
|-project_name
|  |-settings.py
|  |-urls.py
|  |-db.sqlite3
|  |....
|
|-app_name1
|  |-templates
|  |  |-app_name1
|  |  |  |-template-extend-no-nav-base.html
|  |  |-no-nav-base.html
|  |-views.py
|  |-urls.py
|  |-admin.py
|
|-app_name2
|  |...
|
|-static
|  |
|  |-js
|  |  |-bootstrap.min.js
|  |  |-bootstrap-theme.js
|  |-css
|  |  |-bootstrap.min.css
|  |-fonts
|
|-templates
|  |-base.html
```

上のディレクトリ構成の`template-extend-no-nav-base.html`を表示してみたのですが、botstrapが上のエラー(404)で適用されませんでした。以下に、no-nav-base.htmlとtemplate-extend-no-nav-base.htmlを示します。

```html
#no-nav-base.html

{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            {%block content %}
            {{ content }}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <script src="{% static 'js/iquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
#template-extend-no-nav-base.html

{% extends "no-nav-base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <p>ログインしてください。</p>
            <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}">Twitterログイン</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

ファイル名などは実際の名前とは一部変えているので間違いがあるかもしれません。どこが間違っているのかわかりましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STATICFILES_DIRS が STATICFILES_DIRになっていました。